# How to see mysql activity logs, audit table did not record anything

Tags: mysql

something happened and our staging db has removed many tables, need to know what happened and when. we are using MySQL
audit table doesn't seem to record anything

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL binary log will record all queries that affect any rows - but will only do you any good if it's enabled.

Look for a `log-bin` setting in your `my.cnf`.

Comment: it is enabled, how can we read it?

Comment: @learner If no path is specified in the option's configuration, then the files should be in the data location, probably `/var/lib/mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

If binary log is enabled, it can be read with [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html):

```
shell> mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/mysqld-bin.000084
```